# How do I save the inputs of an HTML form into a JSON file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, local-storage

As my question already reveals, I am trying to save inputs from an HTML form to a json file - However I only get to save the inputs to the localStorage.

```
let movies = [];
        const addMovie = (ev)=>{
            ev.preventDefault();
            let movie = {
                id: Date.now(),
                title: document.getElementById('title').value,
                year: document.getElementById('yr').value
            }
            movies.push(movie);
            document.querySelector('form').reset();

            //saving to localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(movies) );
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
            document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addMovie);
        });
```

Now, I've already tried the fs.writeFile methods but somehow my pc doesn't want to import fs.
So I'm asking if there's another way to write the inputs into JSON or how to fix the import fs bug.

Comment: What should the `fs` be?

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand your question correctly, but I wanted it to be something like this: fs.writeFile('data.json', movies)

Comment: To saturday7: what is the `fs` object?

Comment: fs is a node.js file system that allows you to read and write files and in this case it should've read the "movie" array and write it into the JSON file

Comment: node.js? It looks like that you are in a browser, aren't you?

Comment: yeah I am in a browser but the JSON isn't

Comment: If you are in a browser, you are not able to use node.js framework. You must constrain yourself to the API of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

In a web browser, you can invoke download in multiple ways. One of possibilities are [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)ing a window, redirection, or creating a link and invoking its click method.

```js
const jsonToDownload = '{"foo":42}'

function download() {
  const aElem = document.createElement("A")
  aElem.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + jsonToDownload
  aElem.download = 'filename.json'
  aElem.click()
}
```

```html
<button onclick=download()>Download</button>
```

You can use any filename. Just set the `download` attribute on the link to the filename.

If you want do download binary or large data, using BLOB object might be better idea. It is quite simple – create the BLOB, generate its URL, initiate the download and revoke the URL of the BLOB.

```js
const jsonToDownload = '{"foo":42}'

function download() {
  const blob = new Blob([jsonToDownload, ], {
    type: 'application/json',
  })
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const aElem = document.createElement("A")
  aElem.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + jsonToDownload
  aElem.download = 'a'
  aElem.click()
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}
```

```html
<button onclick=download()>Download</button>
```

Please note that the snippet above will not probably work, because StackOverflow's iframe usage prohibits this behavior in some browsers. Copy the code in your own HTML file adn try it there.

Comment: is there also a way to append the data to an already existing json file?

Comment: No. Think of the browser as a isolated sandbox environment for the page. All operations with the files available in the browser are only form uploads (related to HTML forms, not JavaScript), reading files selected by a `<input>` with `type=file` and issuing a download (or playing audio/video, showing image, using a BLOB/other URL as a source of something etc). You can use network operations. To concatenate files, you can use a `<input type=file>` to select the original file, append it in the script and provide a way to download the concatenated file. Or you can use network, of course.